# No sound after returning to my player app

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I built a simple player app by using AVPlayer. By tapping one button the playback starts, by tapping an other button it stops. This works fine so far.
After stopping the playback I press the home button to return to the home screen. I start another player app (f.e. Spotify) and listen to some music there.
Then I return to my own app and tap the play button and - there's suddenly no sound. The mp3 file is playing but I can't hear anything.
Is there a special function to call in viewDidAppear or something like this?

Comment: Post some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using bellow code

any questions call me back, if it does not work post your player code so I can help you

```
@IBAction func playButtonAction(_ sender: Any){
    if avAudio != nil {

        if avAudio.isPlaying {
            avAudio.pause()

        } else {
            avAudio.play()
        }

    } else {
        avAudio = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: song.assetURL!)
        avAudio.delegate = self as AVAudioPlayerDelegate
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did and then I used:

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ...)
    if (audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()) {
      audioPlayer!.play()
    }

and

    audioPlayer!.stop()

Comment: By this code snippet I couldn't identify what may be occurring, try to post the full code of the player. I edited my previous response with the method I use where "song" is audio that I want to play.